# History of prime distribution $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\pi(x)}{x}=0$

Tags: number-theory

Let $\pi(x)$ be the prime counting function. It is well-known that
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\pi(x)}{x}=0.$$
My question is who is the first person to prove this result?
Did Eratosthenes prove this theorem for the first time?

Comment: This was not known until Chebyshev proved a stronger result (1849).

Comment: Ancient Greeks did not entertain propositions of this sort, even as a conjecture (of Legendre and Gauss), it only appeared at the very end of 18th century. Wikipedia has a detailed [History of the proof of the asymptotic law of prime numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#History_of_the_proof_of_the_asymptotic_law_of_prime_numbers).